# R highcharter bar color based on value

Tags: r, highcharts, colors

I have the following R code:

```
library(highcharter)
library(magrittr)
r1 <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
r2 <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
color <- c('#f0f0f5','#00a1cd','#0058b8')

df <- data.frame(r1, r2, color)

hc <- highchart() %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = df$r1) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = df$r2, type = "bar")
hc
```

I would like the bars to have the color specified in `df$color`. But with my current code, all bars have the same color. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not know about `highcharter` but seems a nice package. It seems to rely on correct column names. In your example, you have apparently used wrong names. Categories apparently need a col named "name" and your colors a column called "color" (which you had already).

```
df <- data.frame(name = c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope'), y = c(21000, 23400, 26800), color = c('#f0f0f5','#00a1cd','#0058b8'))

highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = 'bar', polar = FALSE) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = df$name) %>% 
  hc_add_series(df)
```

I also used `hc_chart` instead of putting the type into `hc_add_series`, following some examples in http://jkunst.com/highcharter/highcharts.html. This might have helped to.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I figured if I named the column with the colors properly it should work. But you are right, all columns need to be named correctly for it to work. You're solution fixed the problem. :)

Comment: can this be used with `stacking`?

Comment: @Laurence_jj maybe worth a follow up question. Please don't forget to include a reproducible example, e.g., as in my answer